# Paging en listview en C#

Tags: c#, .net

necesito de su ayuda, estoy haciendo una aplicacion en windows form en C# que consulta datos de un vector, y lo muestra en un listview, el problema esta en que cuando tiene mas de 7 registro, se hace incomodo ver los datos. Entonces se me ocurrio agregar uns botones de "atras" y "adelante", para navegar como si fuera una pagina. Investigando lei algo de paginar los datos (paging), pero todas las referencias la hacen en datagrid o con conexion a una base de datos y esos no son mis casos, debe ser una tonteria, pero como me estoy iniciando en este mundo, no soy muy diestro. Ayuda y agradecido de antemano. Aqui le dejo el codigo y el formulario realizado:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PagedList;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication6{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

        Random r = new Random();

        string[] datos=new string[5];
        datos[0] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
        datos[1] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
        datos[2] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
        datos[3] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
        datos[4] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();

       ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0]);
       lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1]);
       lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2]);
       lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3]);
       lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4]);
       listView1.Items.Add(lista);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Amigos! Lo pude realizar!
Aqui le dejo el codigo fuente y el formulario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OLAFF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte y = 1;
        byte z = 1;
        string[] datos = new string[220];
        double size = 0;
        double total_pag = 0;
        int pag = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            for (x = 0; x < 220; x++)
            {
                datos[x] = "prueba" + x;
            }
            size = datos.Length;
            total_pag = size / 42;
            total_pag = Math.Ceiling(total_pag);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(pag);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(total_pag);

            for (z = 0; z < pag * 7 * 6; z += 6)
            {
                ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0+z]);
                lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1+z]);
                lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2+z]);
                lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3 + z]);
                lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4 + z]);
                lista.SubItems.Add(datos[5 + z]);

                listView1.Items.Add(lista);
            }

        }

        private void btnAdelante_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int s;
            int pag_actual;
            int tamano;
            int ult_posicion;
            int ult_filas;
            int ult_elementos;
            int sss;
            int ssss;

            if (pag < total_pag)
            {

                if (total_pag - pag == 1)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Clear();
                    pag = pag + 1;
                    pag_actual = pag - 1;
                    tamano = datos.Length;
                    ult_posicion = tamano - (7 * 6 * pag_actual);
                    ult_filas = (ult_posicion / 6);
                    ult_elementos = ult_posicion % 6;

                    for (sss = 7 * 6 * pag_actual; sss <= ult_filas * 6 * 7 * pag_actual; sss += 6)
                    {
                        ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0 + sss]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1 + sss]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2 + sss]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3 + sss]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4 + sss]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[5 + sss]);

                        listView1.Items.Add(lista);
                    }


                    for (ssss = (ult_filas * 6 * 7 * pag_actual) + 6; ssss <= (ult_filas * 6 * 7 * pag_actual) + 6 + ult_elementos; ssss+=6)
                    {
                        ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0 + ssss]);
                        if (ult_elementos>1)
                        {
                            lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1 + ssss]);
                        }
                        if (ult_elementos > 2)
                        {
                            lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2 + ssss]);
                        }
                        if (ult_elementos > 3)
                        {
                            lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3 + ssss]);
                        }
                        if (ult_elementos > 4)
                        {
                            lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4 + ssss]);
                        }
                        if (ult_elementos > 5)
                        {
                            lista.SubItems.Add(datos[5 + ssss]);
                        }
                        listView1.Items.Add(lista);
                    }
                    label3.Text = Convert.ToString(pag);
                }
                else
                {

                    listView1.Items.Clear();
                    pag = pag + 1;
                    pag_actual = pag - 1;
                    label3.Text = Convert.ToString(pag);
                    for (s = 7 * 6 * pag_actual; s < pag * 7 * 6; s += 6)
                    {
                        ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0 + s]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1 + s]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2 + s]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3 + s]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4 + s]);
                        lista.SubItems.Add(datos[5 + s]);
                        listView1.Items.Add(lista);
                    }
                }
                }
        }



        private void btnAtras_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int pag_actual2;
            int ss;
            if (pag>1){
                pag = pag - 1;
                label3.Text = Convert.ToString(pag);
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                pag_actual2 = Convert.ToInt16(pag - 1);
                for (ss = 7 * 6 * pag_actual2; ss < pag * 7 * 6; ss += 6)
                {
                    ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(datos[0 + ss]);
                    lista.SubItems.Add(datos[1 + ss]);
                    lista.SubItems.Add(datos[2 + ss]);
                    lista.SubItems.Add(datos[3 + ss]);
                    lista.SubItems.Add(datos[4 + ss]);
                    lista.SubItems.Add(datos[5 + ss]);
                    listView1.Items.Add(lista);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]